# Persisting Address Bar in iOS 13.2 after 'Adding To Home Screen'

Tags: html, ios, reactjs, ipad, progressive-web-apps

Since upgrading iPads to iOS 13.2, websites that have been 'added to home screen' and are in 'guided access' mode show a persisted address/tool bar. We have the proper `meta` tags, i.e.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

but are still seeing the address/tool bar:

[image]

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a `manifest.json` file with `"display": "standalone"`.